# Object is created but seems to be sharing a reference

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am building an editor, in the editor when you press play it converts a bunch of objects to a `Prefab` (which explains to my engine how to build an object). When I then stop them I would like to rebuild the `Prefab` again and it should be back to its original state (before play was pressed). The issue that I am having is that when `stop` is pressed the items don't go back to their original state. They seem to stay in the state that they are in when stop was pressed.

Here is the class that I am using to convert Prefabs back and forth:

```
class Prefab {

    public name: string;
    public components: PrefabComponent[] = [];

    public static create(gameObject: GameObject): Prefab {
        let prefab = new Prefab;
        prefab.name = gameObject.name;
        gameObject.components.forEach(comp => {
            let prefabComp = new PrefabComponent;
            prefabComp.name = comp.name;
            for (let c in comp) {
                let prefabProp = new PrefabProperty;
                prefabProp.name = c;
                if (typeof comp[c] == 'object') {
                    prefabProp.value = Object.create(comp[c]);
                } else {
                    prefabProp.value = comp[c];
                }
                prefabComp.properties.push(prefabProp);
            }
            prefab.components.push(prefabComp);
        });
        return prefab;
    }

    public static toObject(prefab: Prefab): GameObject {
        let gameObject = new GameObject(prefab.name);
        prefab.components.forEach(comp => {
            let newComp;
            if (comp.name.toLowerCase() != 'transform') {
                newComp = gameObject.addComponent(comp.name);
            }
            if (!newComp) {
                newComp = gameObject.getComponent(comp.name);
            }
            comp.properties.forEach(prop => {
                if (prop.value instanceof Sprite) {
                    newComp[prop.name] = Sprite.create(prop.value.path);
                } else if (typeof prop.value == 'object') {
                    newComp[prop.name] = Object.create(prop.value);
                } else {
                    newComp[prop.name] = prop.value;
                }
            });
        });
        return gameObject;
    }

}

class PrefabComponent {

    public name: string;
    public properties: PrefabProperty[] = [];

}

class PrefabProperty {

    public name: string;
    public value: any;

}
```

Here is how I am starting and stopping the game:

```
play.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Game has started
    // Stop was pressed
    if (game instanceof SpyNginMain) {
        game.stopGame();
        game = null;
        play.classList.remove('active');
        pause.classList.remove('active');
        // Reset the editor
        EditorObjectManager.clear();
        prefabs.forEach(prefab => {
            EditorObjectManager.addItem(Prefab.toObject(prefab));
        });
        updateScene();
    }
    // Game has not started
    // Play was pressed
    else {
        game = new SpyNginMain();
        prefabs = [];
        EditorObjectManager.items.forEach(item => {
            prefabs.push(Prefab.create(item));
        });
        game.init(scene, prefabs);
        game.startGame();
        play.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

The issue seems to be when I try to convert Object with the `PrefabProperty` class. I think that it isn't creating an instance but is creating a reference to the original, but I am not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create` method will certainly retain references to the original object because of the following code:

```
    if (typeof comp[c] == 'object') {
        prefabProp.value = Object.create(comp[c]);
    } else {
        prefabProp.value = comp[c];
    }
```

The `Object.create` call creates a new object with the original object as its prototype, so if you subsequently add/modify/delete a property in the original object, the changes will also appear in the newly created object.

I think what you meant to do here is to *clone* the original object? There are many existing implementations for cloning (eg lodash's [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)).

I would replace all five lines quoted above with a single `clone(comp[c])` call, since your `typeof` check is not reliable in other ways too (eg `typeof null == 'object'` is true, `typeof [1,2,3] == 'object'` is true, etc).

Comment: I think it is working, I am still testing it though.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a typescript thing but seeing this without parenthesis looks incorrect:

```
let prefabComp = new PrefabComponent;
```

I believe it should be:

```
let prefabComp = new PrefabComponent();
```

Also this line here: `newComp[prop.name] = prop.value;` if prop.value is an object, that component would get referenced from the old one.

A good way to see if the object is the same one is `===`.

```
const a = {'a': 'hello'};
console.log(a === a); // true
const b = {'a': 'hello'};
console.log(a === b); // false
```

Comment: Creating a new instance without the `()` is valid syntax, so I don't think that is the issue, `newComp[prop.name] = prop.value` is an object, but when I check using `typeof prop.value` and create an instance I get an error at run time.

Comment: I tried creating the object differently, but it still keeps the reference, and I don't get any errors